# ez publish 2.2.9 image html link code not working after save

Tags: ezpublish

I have a problem with links in articles. If I create new article and some tag links add to in, after publish all links is broken. All URLs are rewritten to '\'. It's a new empty installation of eZPublish. I do not know, what to do.

Anybody help?

```
<p>&nbsp;<img src="\"http://delauto.lt/images/cfmoto.png\"" width="\"1379\"" height="\"242\"" border="\"0\"" /></p>
```

I think the problem is in the quotation marks ?

Editor is mceEditor

Answer (score 0):

eZ Publish 1.x and 2.x (at any version) does not provide or support the mceEditor or any editor for the ezxml article content input format (by default).

eZ Publish 1.x and 2.x (by default) store ezarticle object content in ezxml (an xml based format, using the older version of this library / syntax) which (in general) does not support the storage of html (formatting) input like the input you suggest your trying to do.

In while ground breaking, the ezxml format was quite limited in many regards and frustrating to some developers who may have not quite had the understanding why it was so important or how it would become a killer feature in future cms systems.

In the default ezarticle module administrator ui you would input ezxml (an old version of this library / syntax) instead of html.

Here is an example of how you would include an image (which would require you upload the image into the image manager (separate module)):

```
 <image id="1" align="float" size="small" />
```

Where did you get your copy of eZ Publish 2.2.9? This might help us all try to reproduce the problem and provide more helpful and specific answers.

It sounds like your using a custom implementation (with custom features) or not understanding the underlaying content storage format your required to use in a default installation.